# Find distance between two points on map using Google Map API V2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am using google map api v2 in my android application, I am able to show the map and put markers on it, but now I am stuck with the  problem in which I need to find out the distance between two markers or points placed on map, I have already gone through the  docs but didn't find anything helpful in this case.

If anyone knows how to solve this then please help me.

Thanks

Comment: There could be a misconception of what is distance here, you should recheck the difference between distance and displacement. AFAIK Google Map API only provides a displacement between two points rather than a distance which you would probably handle or compute it by yourself.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the following method that will give you accurate result

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter = valueResult % 1000;
        int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
    }
```

Comment: why are you multplying it to `c`? What does `c` do?

Comment: Really not the best practice... You should use location http://stackoverflow.com/a/15351351/1291650

Comment: Seems like a complicated solution for an ordinary programmer to come up with by themselves.

Comment: Do not use this anymore. Use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/

Answer (score 90):

In `Google Map API V2` You have `LatLng` objects so you can't use `distanceTo` (yet).

You can then use the following code considering **oldPosition** and **newPosition** are `LatLng` objects :

```
// The computed distance is stored in results[0].
//If results has length 2 or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1].
//If results has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(oldPosition.latitude, oldPosition.longitude,
                newPosition.latitude, newPosition.longitude, results);
```

For more *informations* about the `Location` class see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

Answer (score 68):

**You should use the android Location**

You can do:

```
location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

And also:

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(latLongA.latitude, latLongA.longitude,
                         latLongB.latitude, latLongB.longitude,
                         results);
```

And you will get the distance in meters between location1 and location2 in meters.
And beetween latLongA ant latLongB.

Using [location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).

Comment: You cannot do that because in Google API V2 there's no `Location` objects

Comment: This is by far the easiest way! Also see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30419112/3879470) for distance between current location and marker.

Comment: Location.distanceBetween is a void method, how can you get result from void method?

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue you can get it from results[0] -> the value is in meters

Comment: @ I want distance in `Km` how can I achieve this?

Comment: @SagarHudge Are you serious? 1 km == 1000 m... Just use Math

Comment: It does not provide accurate results. What if someone needs the actual route distance between two points, not just a direct poly line distance?

Answer (score 48):

Coming rather late, but seeing that this is one of the top results on Google search for the topic I'll share another way:

Use a one-liner with Googles **utility class SphericalUtil**

```
SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(latLngFrom, latLngTo)
```

You will need the [utility classes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).

You can simply include them in your project using gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this one... Is there any way to find out time between two points using SphericalUtil ?

Comment: this method no longer works as the dependency has been removed.

Comment: I just checked and it works fine for me. I updated the version to 0.5, but 0.4 also worked. See the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup

Comment: It works, but compare to goole direction api, it is giving 1 or 2 km less distance not accurate.

Comment: @AshwinH This does not compute directions on streets but the straight line distance, two very different things. So if you want to know how far you need to travel, do not use this, you will need directions instead.

Answer (score 17):

All this answers will give you the distance in a straight line. If you need to get the distance by road, you have to parse the JSON that Google sends you back after calling his service. You can use this method:

```
public String getDistance(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2){
    String parsedDistance;
    String response;
        Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");
                    final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                    JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                    JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
                    parsedDistance=distance.getString("text");

                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return parsedDistance;
}
```

lat1 and lon1 are coordinates of origin, lat2 and lon2 are coordinates of destination.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for the earth land, because the distance measures by the roads not by a strait line, thank you.

Comment: "error_message": "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project..."

Comment: It is better (in performance) to use AsyncTask.

Answer (score 13):

@salman khan what Usman Kurd suggested is perfect. Only thing i found which can be corrected is that "For google maps v2 we use **LatLng** class. So below is the code of Usman Kurd that can be used for Google Maps v2. I checked it works perfect.

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        int Radius=6371;//radius of earth in Km         
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult= Radius*c;
        double km=valueResult/1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int kmInDec =  Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter=valueResult%1000;
        int  meterInDec= Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        Log.i("Radius Value",""+valueResult+"   KM  "+kmInDec+" Meter   "+meterInDec);

        return Radius * c;
     }
```

Comment: what is c?? why we need to multiply by c

Answer (score 6):

simple util function to calculate distance between two geopoints:

```
public static long getDistanceMeters(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {

    double l1 = toRadians(lat1);
    double l2 = toRadians(lat2);
    double g1 = toRadians(lng1);
    double g2 = toRadians(lng2);

    double dist = acos(sin(l1) * sin(l2) + cos(l1) * cos(l2) * cos(g1 - g2));
    if(dist < 0) {
        dist = dist + Math.PI;
    }

    return Math.round(dist * 6378100);
}
```

Comment: Why do you increase distance by PI?

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
double distance;
Location locationA = new Location("");
locationA.setLatitude(main_Latitude);
locationA.setLongitude(main_Longitude);
Location locationB = new Location("");
locationB.setLatitude(sub_Latitude);
locationB.setLongitude(sub_Longitude);
distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;
kmeter.setText(String.valueOf(distance));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+distance, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();double distance;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public class GoogleDirection {

    public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";
    public final static String MODE_BICYCLING = "bicycling";

    public final static String STATUS_OK = "OK";
    public final static String STATUS_NOT_FOUND = "NOT_FOUND";
    public final static String STATUS_ZERO_RESULTS = "ZERO_RESULTS";
    public final static String STATUS_MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED = "MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED";
    public final static String STATUS_INVALID_REQUEST = "INVALID_REQUEST";
    public final static String STATUS_OVER_QUERY_LIMIT = "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT";
    public final static String STATUS_REQUEST_DENIED = "REQUEST_DENIED";
    public final static String STATUS_UNKNOWN_ERROR = "UNKNOWN_ERROR";

    public final static int SPEED_VERY_FAST = 1;
    public final static int SPEED_FAST = 2;
    public final static int SPEED_NORMAL = 3;
    public final static int SPEED_SLOW = 4;
    public final static int SPEED_VERY_SLOW = 5;

    private OnDirectionResponseListener mDirectionListener = null;
    private OnAnimateListener mAnimateListener = null;

    private boolean isLogging = false;

    private LatLng animateMarkerPosition = null;
    private LatLng beginPosition = null;
    private LatLng endPosition = null;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> animatePositionList = null;
    private Marker animateMarker = null;
    private Polyline animateLine = null;
    private GoogleMap gm = null;
    private int step = -1;
    private int animateSpeed = -1;
    private int zoom = -1;
    private double animateDistance = -1;
    private double animateCamera = -1;
    private double totalAnimateDistance = 0;
    private boolean cameraLock = false;
    private boolean drawMarker = false;
    private boolean drawLine = false;
    private boolean flatMarker = false;
    private boolean isCameraTilt = false;
    private boolean isCameraZoom = false;
    private boolean isAnimated = false;

    private Context mContext = null;

    public GoogleDirection(Context context) { 
        mContext = context;
    }

    public String request(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
        final String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=" + mode;

        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "URL : " + url);
        new RequestTask().execute(new String[]{ url });
        return url;
    }

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
        protected Document doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url[0]);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                return builder.parse(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
            super.onPostExecute(doc);
            if(mDirectionListener != null)
                mDirectionListener.onResponse(getStatus(doc), doc, GoogleDirection.this);
        }

        private String getStatus(Document doc) {
            NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
            Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
            if(isLogging)
                Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Status : " + node1.getTextContent());
            return node1.getTextContent();
        }
    }

    public void setLogging(boolean state) {
        isLogging = state;
    }

    public String getStatus(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Status : " + node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String[] getDurationText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        String[] arr_str = new String[nl1.getLength() - 1];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
            arr_str[i] = node2.getTextContent();
            if(isLogging)
                Log.i("GoogleDirection", "DurationText : " + node2.getTextContent());
        }
        return arr_str;
    }

    public int[] getDurationValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        int[] arr_int = new int[nl1.getLength() - 1];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
            arr_int[i] = Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
            if(isLogging)
                Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Duration : " + node2.getTextContent());
        }
        return arr_int;
    }

    public String getTotalDurationText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getTotalDurationValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String[] getDistanceText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        String[] arr_str = new String[nl1.getLength() - 1];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
            arr_str[i] = node2.getTextContent();
            if(isLogging)
                Log.i("GoogleDirection", "DurationText : " + node2.getTextContent());
        }
        return arr_str;
    }

    public int[] getDistanceValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        int[] arr_int = new int[nl1.getLength() - 1];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl1.getLength() - 1 ; i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
            Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
            arr_int[i] = Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
            if(isLogging)
                Log.i("GoogleDirection", "Duration : " + node2.getTextContent());
        }
        return arr_int;
    }

    public String getTotalDistanceText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getTotalDistanceValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "TotalDuration : " + node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "StartAddress : " + node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "StartAddress : " + node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        if(isLogging)
            Log.i("GoogleDirection", "CopyRights : " + node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude
                            , arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getSection(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    public PolylineOptions getPolyline(Document doc, int width, int color) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> arr_pos = getDirection(doc);
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(dpToPx(width)).color(color);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_pos.size() ; i++)        
            rectLine.add(arr_pos.get(i));
        return rectLine;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double)lat / 1E5, (double)lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
        return px;
    }

    public void setOnDirectionResponseListener(OnDirectionResponseListener listener) {
        mDirectionListener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnAnimateListener(OnAnimateListener listener) {
        mAnimateListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnDirectionResponseListener {
        public void onResponse(String status, Document doc, GoogleDirection gd);
    }

    public interface OnAnimateListener {
        public void onFinish();
        public void onStart();
        public void onProgress(int progress, int total);
    }

    public void animateDirection(GoogleMap gm, ArrayList<LatLng> direction, int speed
            , boolean cameraLock, boolean isCameraTilt, boolean isCameraZoom
            , boolean drawMarker, MarkerOptions mo, boolean flatMarker
            , boolean drawLine, PolylineOptions po) {
        if(direction.size() > 1) {
            isAnimated = true;
            animatePositionList = direction;
            animateSpeed = speed;
            this.drawMarker = drawMarker;
            this.drawLine = drawLine;
            this.flatMarker = flatMarker;
            this.isCameraTilt = isCameraTilt;
            this.isCameraZoom = isCameraZoom;
            step = 0;
            this.cameraLock = cameraLock;
            this.gm = gm;

            setCameraUpdateSpeed(speed);

            beginPosition = animatePositionList.get(step);
            endPosition = animatePositionList.get(step + 1);
            animateMarkerPosition = beginPosition;

            if(mAnimateListener != null)
                mAnimateListener.onProgress(step, animatePositionList.size());

            if(cameraLock) {
                float bearing = getBearing(beginPosition, endPosition);
                CameraPosition.Builder cameraBuilder = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(animateMarkerPosition).bearing(bearing);

                if(isCameraTilt) 
                    cameraBuilder.tilt(90);
                else 
                    cameraBuilder.tilt(gm.getCameraPosition().tilt);

                if(isCameraZoom) 
                    cameraBuilder.zoom(zoom);
                else 
                    cameraBuilder.zoom(gm.getCameraPosition().zoom);

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = cameraBuilder.build();
                gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }

            if(drawMarker) {
                if(mo != null)
                    animateMarker = gm.addMarker(mo.position(beginPosition));
                else 
                    animateMarker = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(beginPosition));

                if(flatMarker) {
                    animateMarker.setFlat(true);

                    float rotation = getBearing(animateMarkerPosition, endPosition) + 180;
                    animateMarker.setRotation(rotation);
                }
            }


            if(drawLine) {
                if(po != null) 
                    animateLine = gm.addPolyline(po.add(beginPosition)
                            .add(beginPosition).add(endPosition)
                            .width(dpToPx((int)po.getWidth())));
                else 
                    animateLine = gm.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .width(dpToPx(5)));
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(r, speed);
            if(mAnimateListener != null)
                mAnimateListener.onStart();
        }
    }

    public void cancelAnimated() {
        isAnimated = false;
    }

    public boolean isAnimated() {
        return isAnimated;
    }

    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            animateMarkerPosition = getNewPosition(animateMarkerPosition, endPosition);

            if(drawMarker)
                animateMarker.setPosition(animateMarkerPosition);


            if(drawLine) {
                List<LatLng> points = animateLine.getPoints();
                points.add(animateMarkerPosition);
                animateLine.setPoints(points);
            }

            if((animateMarkerPosition.latitude == endPosition.latitude 
                    && animateMarkerPosition.longitude == endPosition.longitude)) {
                if(step == animatePositionList.size() - 2) {
                    isAnimated = false;
                    totalAnimateDistance = 0;
                    if(mAnimateListener != null)
                        mAnimateListener.onFinish();
                } else {
                    step++;
                    beginPosition = animatePositionList.get(step);
                    endPosition = animatePositionList.get(step + 1);
                    animateMarkerPosition = beginPosition;

                    if(flatMarker && step + 3 < animatePositionList.size() - 1) {
                        float rotation = getBearing(animateMarkerPosition, animatePositionList.get(step + 3)) + 180;
                        animateMarker.setRotation(rotation);
                    }

                    if(mAnimateListener != null)
                        mAnimateListener.onProgress(step, animatePositionList.size());
                }
            }

            if(cameraLock && (totalAnimateDistance > animateCamera || !isAnimated)) {
                totalAnimateDistance = 0;
                float bearing = getBearing(beginPosition, endPosition);
                CameraPosition.Builder cameraBuilder = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(animateMarkerPosition).bearing(bearing);

                if(isCameraTilt) 
                    cameraBuilder.tilt(90);
                else 
                    cameraBuilder.tilt(gm.getCameraPosition().tilt);

                if(isCameraZoom) 
                    cameraBuilder.zoom(zoom);
                else 
                    cameraBuilder.zoom(gm.getCameraPosition().zoom);

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = cameraBuilder.build();
                gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            }

            if(isAnimated) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(r, animateSpeed);
            }
        }
    };

    public Marker getAnimateMarker() {
        return animateMarker;
    }

    public Polyline getAnimatePolyline() {
        return animateLine;
    }

    private LatLng getNewPosition(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
        double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude); 
        double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

        double dis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lat, 2) + Math.pow(lng, 2));
        if(dis >= animateDistance) {
            double angle = -1;

            if(begin.latitude <= end.latitude && begin.longitude <= end.longitude)
                angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat));
            else if(begin.latitude > end.latitude && begin.longitude <= end.longitude)
                angle = (90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90;
            else if(begin.latitude > end.latitude && begin.longitude > end.longitude)
                angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180;
            else if(begin.latitude <= end.latitude && begin.longitude > end.longitude)
                angle = (90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270;

            double x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * animateDistance;
            double y = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * animateDistance;
            totalAnimateDistance += animateDistance;
            double finalLat = begin.latitude + x;
            double finalLng = begin.longitude + y;

            return new LatLng(finalLat, finalLng);
        } else {
            return end;
        }
    }

    private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
        double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude); 
        double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);
         if(begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
            return (float)(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
        else if(begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
            return (float)((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
        else if(begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
            return  (float)(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
        else if(begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
            return (float)((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
         return -1;
    }

    public void setCameraUpdateSpeed(int speed) {       
        if(speed == SPEED_VERY_SLOW) {
            animateDistance = 0.000005;
            animateSpeed = 20;
            animateCamera = 0.0004;
            zoom = 19;
        } else if(speed == SPEED_SLOW) {
            animateDistance = 0.00001;
            animateSpeed = 20;
            animateCamera = 0.0008;
            zoom = 18;
        } else if(speed == SPEED_NORMAL) {
            animateDistance = 0.00005;
            animateSpeed = 20;
            animateCamera = 0.002;
            zoom = 16;
        } else if(speed == SPEED_FAST) {
            animateDistance = 0.0001;
            animateSpeed = 20;
            animateCamera = 0.004;
            zoom = 15;
        } else if(speed == SPEED_VERY_FAST) {
            animateDistance = 0.0005;
            animateSpeed = 20;
            animateCamera = 0.004;
            zoom = 13;
        } else {
            animateDistance = 0.00005;
            animateSpeed = 20;
            animateCamera = 0.002;
            zoom = 16;
        }
    }
}
```

//Main Activity

```
public class MapActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    GoogleMap map = null;
    GoogleDirection gd;

    LatLng start,end;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        start = new LatLng(13.744246499553903, 100.53428772836924);
        end = new LatLng(13.751279688694071, 100.54316081106663);


        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(start, 15));

        gd = new GoogleDirection(this);
        gd.setOnDirectionResponseListener(new GoogleDirection.OnDirectionResponseListener() {
            public void onResponse(String status, Document doc, GoogleDirection gd) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                gd.animateDirection(map, gd.getDirection(doc), GoogleDirection.SPEED_FAST
                        , true, true, true, false, null, false, true, new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(Color.RED));

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(start)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.markera)));

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(end)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.markerb)));

                String TotalDistance = gd.getTotalDistanceText(doc);
                String TotalDuration = gd.getTotalDurationText(doc);
            }
        });

        gd.request(start, end, GoogleDirection.MODE_DRIVING);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The distance between two geo-coordinates can be found by using **[Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)** . This formula is effective to calculate distance in a spherical body i.e earth in our case.

Comment: the thing is earth not spherique but elliptique google use the mercator projection !

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question. Also, it is better to include the essential parts of the linked answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

**THIS IS THE EASY AND PERFECT CODE FOR DURATION AND DISTANCE FINDING**

- Step 1;(add this and sync in your gradle)

  ```
   implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
  ```
- Step 2:(write this in your trigger method)

  ```
   public void clicked(View view) throws JSONException {  

        JSONObject locationJsonObject = new JSONObject();
               locationJsonObject.put("origin", "54.406505,18.67708");
               locationJsonObject.put("destination", "54.446251,18.570993");
               LatlngCalc(locationJsonObject);
   }
  ```
- Step 3:(Copy & Paste in your class)

  ```
   private void LatlngCalc(JSONObject locationJsonObject) throws JSONException {

       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
       String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/" +
                   "json?origins=" + locationJsonObject.getString("origin") + "&destinations=" + locationJsonObject.getString("destination") + "&mode=driving&" +
                   "language=en-EN&sensor=false" + "&key=" + /*Insert Your API Key Here */;

       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
               new Response.Listener<String>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {

                       mTextView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
           }
       });
       queue.add(stringRequest);  
   }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

to get distance between two points try this code..

```
public static float GetDistanceFromCurrentPosition(double lat1,double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
 {
        double earthRadius = 3958.75;

        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);

        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);

        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLng / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLng / 2);

        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

        double dist = earthRadius * c;

        int meterConversion = 1609;

        return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this function. I have used it in my project.

```
public String getDistance(LatLng my_latlong, LatLng frnd_latlong) {
    Location l1 = new Location("One");
    l1.setLatitude(my_latlong.latitude);
    l1.setLongitude(my_latlong.longitude);

    Location l2 = new Location("Two");
    l2.setLatitude(frnd_latlong.latitude);
    l2.setLongitude(frnd_latlong.longitude);

    float distance = l1.distanceTo(l2);
    String dist = distance + " M";

    if (distance > 1000.0f) {
        distance = distance / 1000.0f;
        dist = distance + " KM";
    }
    return dist;
}
```

Comment: You put the name of towns inside location class??

Comment: this function is used to calculate the distance between two points , not for town/street name.

Comment: and please, what is the use the String inside Location constructor... `Location l2 = new Location("Two")`

Comment: each point has a longitude and latitude, suppose here we don't know the name of the place but we can get location data. Here Location l2 = new Location("Two") two is the 2nd place will be identified by Two. It's a tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question with old answers. I want to highlight an updated way of calculating distance between two points. By now we should be familiar with the utility class, "SphericalUtil". You can retrieve the distance using that.

```
double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(origin, dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Google directions Api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=00.00,00.004&destination=00.00,00.00&key=YOUR_MAP_KEY

Parse Api Response:

```
JSONArray jsonArrayRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            if (jsonArrayRoutes.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectRoutes = jsonArrayRoutes.getJSONObject(0);

                if (!jObject.isNull("bounds")) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectBounds = jObject.getJSONObject("bounds");
                    if (!jsonObjectBounds.isNull("northeast")) {
                        JSONObject jsonObjectNorthEast = jsonObjectBounds.getJSONObject("northeast");
                        LatLng latLngNorthEast = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObjectNorthEast.getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(jsonObjectNorthEast.getString("lng")));
                    }
                    if (!jsonObjectBounds.isNull("southwest")) {
                        JSONObject jsonObjectSouthWest = jsonObjectBounds.getJSONObject("southwest");
                        LatLng latLngSouthWest = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObjectSouthWest.getString("lat")), Double.parseDouble(jsonObjectSouthWest.getString("lng")));
                    }
                }

                //Distance & Duration
                JSONArray jsonArrayLegs = jsonObjectRoutes.getJSONArray("legs");
                if (jsonArrayLegs.length() > 0) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectLegs = jsonArrayLegs.getJSONObject(0);

                    JSONObject jsonObjectDistance = jsonObjectLegs.getJSONObject("distance");
                    String distKM = jsonObjectDistance.getString("text");
                    System.out.println("Distance in KM: " + distKM);
                    JSONObject jsonObjectDuration = jsonObjectLegs.getJSONObject("duration");
                    String durTime = jsonObjectDuration.getString("text");
                    System.out.println("Duration: " + durTime);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -6):

In android google maps application there is a very easy way to find distance between 2 locations, to do so follow the following easy steps:

1. when you first open the app go to " your timeline " from the drop
   menue on the top left.
2. once the new windwo opens, chose from the settings on your top right menue and choose "add place".
3. add your places and name them lilke point 1 , point 2 , or any easy name to remember.
4. once your places are added and flagged go back to the main Window in your google app.
5. click on the blue circle with the arrow in your bottom right.
6. a new windwo will open and you can see on the top there are two text fields in which you can add your "from location" and "distance location".
7. click on any text field and type in your saved location in point 3.
8. click on the other text field and add your next saved location.
9. By doing so, google maps will calculate the distance between the two locations and show you the blue path on map ..

Good luck

Comment: The question is about how to find the distance between two points in Android programmatically. This answer is wrong.