# Google direction API gives wrong distance and time duration

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I have implemented the google map api functionality in my android APP.
The google map api give me a correct route(Directions), but it gives wrong distance and time between the two endpoint.

I have implemented this google map api in android, in XML format.
Following are the code that I have used to get the distance between two endpoint.
(I am using the "Driving" mode).

```
public String getDistanceText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }
```

Following are the code to get the time duration between two end point:

```
public String getDurationText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }
```

What wrong I did here?

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: It is already answered:

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2

Answer (score 1):

You read the wrong node. When you want the complete duration for the route you have to read the last durartion-Element

from

```
NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");   
Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
```

to

```
NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLenght()-1);
NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
```