# how to get distance between two positions in map?

Tags: android, eclipse

how can i get the distance between two points and show that distance in Google map? please help me. 
i have tried to get direction between two points but i am not able to get the distance between them.. my code is:

```
 private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {

    String origin = "origin=" + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
    String destination = "destination=" + mDestLocation.latitude + "," + mDestLocation.longitude;
    /*String origin = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
    String destination =mDestLocation.latitude + "," + mDestLocation.longitude;*/


    String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|"
            + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()
            + "|" + "|" + mDestLocation.latitude + ","
            + mDestLocation.longitude;
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String params = origin + "&" + destination + "&" + waypoints + "&" + sensor;
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
            + output + "?" + params;

    return url;
 }
```

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=AIzaSyAOngZ2BFuDeE2J2pwHm9d2Rv6ZnrfZ1JY

Comment: in this service we r getting distance parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this is in the following link :
[Find distance between two points on map using Google Map API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2)
Hope this will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use - yourLocation.distanceTo(otherLocation);

where
float distanceTo (Location dest)
Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and the given location. Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.

Parameters
dest    Location: the destination location;