# How to calculate Distance between two coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, distance

i try to get distance between two Positions and tried the following code:

```
Location startPoint=new Location("locationA");
    startPoint.setLatitude(17.372102);
    startPoint.setLongitude(78.484196);

    Location endPoint=new Location("locationA");
    endPoint.setLatitude(17.375775);
    endPoint.setLongitude(78.469218);

    double distance= (int) startPoint.distanceTo(endPoint);
    TextView dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
  dis.setText((int) distance);
```

unfortunately my app is crashing always if i try to calculate the distance between this two points

Comment: use `dis.setText(String.valueOf((int) distance));`

Comment: **duplicate** of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2).

Comment: did you try with `haversine formula` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem in your code

```
 TextView dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
 dis.setText((int) distance);
```

setText() method expects string and you are setting int. Convert distance to string. You can do as

1) dis.setText(String.valueOf(distance));

OR

2)dis.setText("" +distance);

hope this helps

Comment: I am glad that I was helpful.