# How get duration in mins from a marker another google maps

Tags: java, android

How i can to get travel duration in MINS from point A to B in Google maps, below i attach my code fragment:

```
Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
locationB.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

double kms = distance / 1000 ;
String distanceKm = new DecimalFormat("#.0").format(kms);

Log.v("log", "distance " + distance);
tv3.setText(distanceKm + "Kms");
```

Thnks for any help

Comment: `time = distance / speed`. Also note the `distanceTo` returns the displacement not the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link google provide direction api it give all the information about source to destination place. read this all things you getting your question solution.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

Comment: you can also refer this link for manual find distance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2