# How to calculate GMSGeometryDistance for android

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I have a problen

Our developer ios has coded this function as follows

```
    let topLeft = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: mapView.bounds.origin)
    let bottomLeft = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: .init(x: mapView.bounds.minX, y: mapView.bounds.maxY))
    let distance = GMSGeometryDistance(topLeft, bottomLeft)
```

This is the introduction of function GMSGeometryDistance in iOs

```
 /**
* Returns the great circle distance between two coordinates, in meters, on Earth.
*
* This is the shortest distance between the two coordinates on the sphere.
*
* Both coordinates must be valid.
*/
 FOUNDATION_EXPORT
 CLLocationDistance GMSGeometryDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2D from, CLLocationCoordinate2D to);
```

I want to do this on google maps of android.

HOW TO CONVERT TO JAVA OR KOTLIN IN ANDROID.

Thanks you.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility

Answer (score 1):

From [Official Documentation of Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils.html#ga21842582cad07506240bb442da5cdd6c):

> `CLLocationDistance GMSGeometryDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2D from,
>                                        CLLocationCoordinate2D to)`
>
> Returns the great circle distance between two coordinates, in meters,
>   on Earth. This is the shortest distance between the two coordinates on
>   the sphere. Both coordinates must be valid.

So, you can:

1) implement in manually follow description on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) (or other resources like [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-distance-two-points-earth/)) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14394403/6950238) answer of [Usman Kurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292203/usman-kurd):

> ```
> public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
>     int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
>     double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
>     double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
>     double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
>     double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
>     double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
>     double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
>     double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
>             + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
>             * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
>             * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
>     double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
>     double valueResult = Radius * c;
>     double km = valueResult / 1;
>     DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
>     int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
>     double meter = valueResult % 1000;
>     int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
>     Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
>             + " Meter   " + meterInDec);
>
>     return Radius * c;
> }
> ```

2) use [`SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(latLngFrom, latLngTo)`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeDistanceBetween-LatLng-LatLng-) from [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility) like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38611867/6950238) answer of [Björn Kechel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497366/bj%c3%b6rn-kechel).