# (Android) Create bounding box with map markers and get width of it in Google Map V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using the following code to zoom and show all markers on a GoogleMap in Android. It works well:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

//the include method will calculate the min and max bound.
builder.include(marker1.getPosition());
builder.include(marker2.getPosition());
builder.include(marker3.getPosition());
builder.include(marker4.getPosition());

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
int padding = (int) (width * 0.10); // offset from edges of the map 10% of screen

CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);

mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

But what I want to do is map all the markers in a bounding box and then get the width of that box. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bounds.northeast` and `bounds.southwest` coordinates

[image: Bounds dimensions]

and find distance between them using `Location.distanceBetween()` method or [any other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14394366/6950238):

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.southwest.longitude,
            bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.northeast.longitude,
            results);
float width_in_meters = results[0];
```

Comment: @Speedy As in your code example: `builder.include(marker1.getPosition());`... Then `LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();` and you can use `bounds.northeast` and `bounds.southwest`.